# trayIcon Notification balloon is not working with Windows 10

Tags: java, c#, windows, windows-10, trayicon

My sample java and C# code are able to popup tray Icon notification balloon with windows 7 and Windows 10.

[image: trayIcon display with simple sample codes]

but while using above sample codes with a legacy product, that uses session-isolation, user-context , impersonation etc etc, It is not working with Windows 10. I can see popup in Windows 7 and other OS but not windows 10.

What could be change in Windows 10 from Windows 7 tray Icon notification Balloon, that is preventing it from popping up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was something to do with context and session isolation in legacy code.

I have resolved it using native win32 api **getEnvironmentStrings()** to get the environment variable of the user process of my application.

Then I triggered a new .exe file by passing the environment variables

Default Environment Variable passed in Java's **exec()** was not enough to trigger .exe file and tp show trayIcon for application running in user-context.

Answer (score 0):

Just a friendly reminder that Java currently supports adding tray icons into the status area and displaying notifications from them, coming through.

Here's the docs for the [SystemTray](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/SystemTray.html) and [TrayIcon](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/TrayIcon.html) classes, for anyone that might be interested. You would be looking for the method `TrayIcon.displayMessage()`.

But now that you mention it, I'd like to know how you handle it with C#.